# Prevent window scroll on navigating dropdown with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm trying to prevent page scrolling on my custom dropdown search using StimulusJS. Much like in gmail, where you can type something in a search box and use arrow keys to navigate. I go to that point where I can navigate the dropdown, but at the same time default behaviour for arrow keys is problematic here.

```js
    // results are divs that get focused
    const results = [node1, node2, node3]

    if (this.listCounter <= -1) { this.listCounter = -1 }
    if (this.listCounter >= results.length) { this.listCounter = results.length - 1 }

    switch (event.key) {
      case 'ArrowDown':
        this.listCounter++
        break
      case 'ArrowUp':
        this.listCounter--
        // when we reach the top we focus back on input element
        if (this.listCounter <= 0) {
          this.userInputTarget.focus()
        }
        break
      default:
        break
    }
    if (results[this.listCounter]) {
      results[this.listCounter].focus()
    }
```

So this works well, but the problem is that pressing arrow keys up/down also invokes scroll on the page. So I tried disabling it, but only when the key is pressed. I don't want to disable this behaviour for the whole page, only when certain elements are focused. Below `console.log()` gets fired, but it doesn't stop the window from being scrolled.

```js
  connect() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.preventKeyboardEvents.bind(this), false)
  }

  preventKeyboardEvents(e) {
    const key = e.key
    const results = window.allMultisearchActiveElements
    const activeElement = results.includes(document.activeElement) || document.activeElement === this.userInputTarget
    if (activeElement && (key === "ArrowDown" || key === "ArrowUp" || key === "Enter")) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('fired')
    }
  }
```

Which part of it am I getting wrong? Is it even possible to `.preventDefault()` only for certain events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comes out it was rather simple.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', this.preventKeyboardEvents.bind(this), false)
```

Since when pressing a key `keydown` event is fired first, I assume it fires a default behaviour of scrolling in the browser window. So using `keyup` was a problem here, because it was fired after the window has received the event from `keydown`.